# Not possible to trigger a script for other users in read-only-mode?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a spreadsheet which I would like to publish in read-only-mode to other users.
Since it contains quite a lot of data, I wrote a script which expands the menu and gives quick-links.

Something like this:

```
function onMyOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var menuEntries = [ {name: "Quicklink 1",     functionName: "selectRow1"},
                      {name: "Quicklink 2",     functionName: "selectRow345"},
                     ];
  ss.addMenu("Quicklinks", menuEntries);
};

function selectRow1() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.setActiveCell("A1");
}
```

I added a trigger for "on Open" and it works like expected for me.

Now, did I understand correctly that there is no way to make this script available to other users/viewers of my spreadsheet?

Comment: Sometimes it is useful to read the documentation... :-)

Answer (score 1):

"They cannot execute when the Spreadsheet is opened in read-only mode." 
[Understanding Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_triggers)

Comment: I did read this. And as far as I understand (my English is not perfect...) it does not apply to scripts that are installed. But installing is possible from the public gallery only. So the only solution would be to publish my script to the script gallery? (which would be useless to all other people...)

Comment: Installable Triggers  
--------------------
Unlike the simple trigger onOpen, the installable trigger can act as the user who installed the trigger.  
----

I understand all that. But I simply do not understand, how to create an installable trigger. And I do not find this information on the google pages. a hint would highly be appreciated.

Comment: To create an installable trigger - in the script editor > Resources > Current project's tiggers > click the link to add one > then choose the options you want from the drop-downs > save.

Comment: I did this. (onMyOpen => FromTable => on open) But viewing my spreadsheet not logged-in, my custom menu does not show up. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It'll appear in view-only mode, but won't be active or available to click.